# How do I require multiple approvals in Phabricator before a revision can be landed?

Tags: phabricator

For example:

- I want all reviewers (that were specified initially or added later) to approve changes, before it becomes accepted.
- I want to specify reviewers whose approval is required and some others whose approval is optional.
- I want to approve a change but at the same time add another reviewer who is also required to approve the change before before it becomes accepted.
- I want all revisions in project A to require at least two people from a specified list before becoming accepted.

Can this sort of control be configured in the UI? In the conf file? When submitting revisions?

Answer (score 4):

I just found out this kind of thing isn't currently possible in Phabricator, there's an open ticket with some comments about it here: https://secure.phabricator.com/T731 (requires login).